# How to Drill into lowest granular data using SSRS, from SSAS Cube

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

I have an SSRS report that uses an SSAS cube as the data source. I want to add drill down functionality that mirrors drilling into a cube from Excel. To be clear, I am not referring to navigating hierarchies. I want to get to the lowest granular level of data used to calculate the aggregations in the cube. Excel does this when you double click in a pivot linked to SSAS, that's what I want.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this from SSRS, or even how excel is doing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use default drill through action or custom drill through action.  Default drill through action displays granular data when you double click the excel cell, which contains aggregate value.